# Flag a Post as a Promotion or Job in Linkedin Groups

Tags: .net, linkedin-api

How can I flag a post as job in LinkedIn using [Groups API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api)?

I have the PostId of my post. The only thing I need to do is to flag that post as a job so that it will be displayed in the Job Discussion section in the LinkedIn Group.

But when I call the API it gives me a 400 Bad Request Error. Does anyone know why?

Comment: You should show some code so people can see exactly what calls you are making.

Comment: Agreed with Casper, please show the code sample so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is something like this function

access_token is your token oauth2

idP  is the id of the post

```
Sub FlagPost(ByVal access_token As String, ByVal idP As String)

    Dim body As String = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><code>job</code>"

    Dim flagasjob As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/posts/" & idP & "/category/code?oauth2_access_token=" & access_token)


    flagasjob.ContentType = "text/xml"
    flagasjob.Method = "PUT"

    Dim codFlag As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding()
    Dim bytesFlag As Byte() = codFlag.GetBytes(body)
    flagasjob.ContentLength = bytesFlag.Length

    Dim stmFlag As Stream
    stmFlag = flagasjob.GetRequestStream()
    stmFlag.Write(bytesFlag, 0, bytesFlag.Length)
    stmFlag.Close()

End Sub
```